# java.nio.file.FileSystemException : cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, cassandra, powermock

I am writing unit-test class using Junit and I am also using power-mocking concept to mock the objects which are created inside the method.

Test Class :

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Client.class)
public class ClientTest {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(ClientTest.class);

private static Client client;

private static DetailsDao detailsDao;
public static Session session;
private static IDevicesDao devicesDao;
private static IUserDao userDao;
private static IDao dao;
private static IValidator validator;



@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws Exception {

    logger.info("*************** Testing ClientTest Started *******************");

    session = Connection.get(); // Here getting error

    detailsDao = mock(DetailsDao.class);
    devicesDao = mock(IDevicesDao.class);
    userDao = mock(UserDao.class);
    validator = mock(IValidator.class);
    dao= mock(IDao.class);

    client = new Client(detailsDao, session, devicesDao, userDao, dao, validator);
}
```

If I romove `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` then its working fine... But I have to run this test using `PowerMockRunner` only.

Exception :

```
[10:45:50] sumanth nama: Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0,      Time elapsed: 1.234 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.service.clientTest  Time elapsed:       1.234 sec  <<< ERROR!
FSWriteError in target\embeddedCassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-4-1470892233532.log
at    org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteWithConfirm(FileUtils.java:135)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteRecursive(FileUtils.java:381)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteRecursive(FileUtils.java:377)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteRecursive(FileUtils.java:377)
at  org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.rmdir(EmbeddedCassandraSer verHelper.java:266)
at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:81)
 at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:64)
at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:56)
at com.charter.aesd.crossmso.wifi.dao.Connection.get(Connection.java:26)
at com.service.ClientTest.setup(ClientTest.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runBefores(ClassRoadie.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at o rg.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException:    target\embeddedCassandra\commitlog\CommitLog-4-1470892233532.log: The process    cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I am not getting ... why it is not able to create cassandra session using  power mock runner....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocked the session also, then it runs without any errors.

replaced

```
session = Connection.get();
```

with

```
session = mock(Session.class);
```